# typescript: requestAnimationFrame and eventlistener:keyup/keydown

Tags: javascript, typescript, addeventlistener, requestanimationframe

This is strange? I cannot make requestAnimationFrame work together with the eventlisteners keyup/down when it is in a typescript class - but it works just fine if I'm outside the class? 
Help me solve this issue or just tell me why It will never work inside a class....

```
  class GameEngine
{
    private aKey:boolean
    private canvas:HTMLCanvasElement;
    private ctx:CanvasRenderingContext2D;

    constructor()
    {
        this.canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById("canvas");
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

        document.addEventListener('keyup', this.keyUp, false);
        document.addEventListener('keydown', this.keyDown, false);

        this.loop();
    }

    private keyDown(event:KeyboardEvent): void
    {
        if (event.repeat) {return};
        console.log("KeyDown");
        console.log(this.aKey);
        if (event.key == 'a')
        {
            this.aKey = true;
            console.log(this.aKey);
        }
    }

    private keyUp(event: KeyboardEvent): void
    {
        if (event.key == 'a')
        {
            this.aKey = false;
        }   
    } 


    private loop()
    {
        console.log(this.aKey);
        if (this.aKey == true) this.ctx.fillRect(10,10,10,10);
        window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));

    }
}

new GameEngine();
```

when I press the 'a' key it writes true/false as expected in the console
but the loop keeps printing 'undefined' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If attaching a handler function to an element using
>   addEventListener(), the value of this inside the handler is a
>   reference to the element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler

In your example `this` is the document object.

Just use `bind` method for your listener and it should work fine. You can read more about it in the link I posted above.

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', this.keyUp.bind(this));
document.addEventListener('keydown', this.keyDown.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks for leading me in the right direction...
i added working code to your answer! 

Do you have an explanation? It works but I don't know why...

Comment: You can find the explanation in the link I posted and at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind. :)